# Hide View Propotional to RecyclerView Scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll, android-recyclerview

In my android application I have a recyclerview and LinearLayout. LinearLayout lies on the top and recyclerview lies down to the linearlayout. what my requirement is when recyclerview starts scrolls the last item, the linearlayout should start hide in propotion to scroll amount.

I have done a little and it works. but it is not proportional to the scroll amount. here is my code

**ScrollListener**

```
public class MyScrollListener extends OnScrollListener {

    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    public MyScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager manager) {
        this.mLayoutManager = manager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

        int visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
        int totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        int firstVisibleItem = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        if (visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItem >= totalItemCount) {
            scrollTheShit(dy * -1, ((View) recyclerView.getChildAt(visibleItemCount - 1)).getWidth());
        }
    }

    public void scrollTheShit(int dy, int widthOfLastChild) {}


}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        final LinearLayoutManager mgr = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mgr);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerAdapter());


        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new MyScrollListener(mgr) {

            @Override
            public void scrollTheShit(int dy, int widthOfLastChild) {

                linearLayout.setY(linearLayout.getY() + dy );
            }
        });
    }


    private class RecyclerAdapter extends Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {


        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 10;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder,
                                     int position) {
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int position) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this)
                    .inflate(R.layout.child, parent, false);
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(v);
            return holder;
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            public ViewHolder(View arg0) {
                super(arg0);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

I have to hide the top section when the below RecyclerView scrolls
[image]

how do I correct this ? anyone please help me

Comment: It would be better if you could show some images or video to illustrate what do you want exactly

Comment: in the above pic, the hello world textview and edit text are inside the linearlayout, when the user starts scrolls the last item of recyclerview. then the top view has to hide

Comment: ok i did small example for you check it out http://amolsawant88.blogspot.in/2015/09/hideshow-view-or-layout-propotional-to.html

Comment: its not small dude, anyway I am checking

Comment: just change... android:layout_gravity="top" in xml file to hide top linear layout

Answer (score 0):

this may help you

QuickReturnRecyclerView.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class QuickReturnRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
    private static final String TAG = QuickReturnRecyclerView.class.getName();

    private View mReturningView;
    private static final int STATE_ONSCREEN = 0;
    private static final int STATE_OFFSCREEN = 1;
    private static final int STATE_RETURNING = 2;
    private int mState = STATE_ONSCREEN;
    private int mMinRawY = 0;
    private int mReturningViewHeight;
    private int mGravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;

    public QuickReturnRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public QuickReturnRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public QuickReturnRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
    }

    /**
     * The view that should be showed/hidden when scrolling the content.
     * Make sure to set the gravity on the this view to either Gravity.Bottom or
     * Gravity.TOP and to put it preferable in a FrameLayout.
     * @param view Any kind of view
     */
    public void setReturningView(View view) {
        mReturningView = view;

        try {
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mReturningView.getLayoutParams();
            mGravity = params.gravity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("The return view need to be put in a FrameLayout");
        }

        measureView(mReturningView);
        mReturningViewHeight = mReturningView.getMeasuredHeight();
        addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerScrollListener());
    }

    private void measureView(View child) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams p = child.getLayoutParams();
        if (p == null) {
            p = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        }

        int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(0, 0, p.width);
        int lpHeight = p.height;
        int childHeightSpec;
        if (lpHeight > 0) {
            childHeightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(lpHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        } else {
            childHeightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        }
        child.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);
    }

    private class RecyclerScrollListener extends OnScrollListener {
        private int mScrolledY;

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            if(mGravity == Gravity.BOTTOM)
                mScrolledY += dy;
            else if(mGravity == Gravity.TOP)
                mScrolledY -= dy;

            if(mReturningView == null)
                return;

            int translationY = 0;
            int rawY = mScrolledY;

            switch (mState) {
                case STATE_OFFSCREEN:
                    if(mGravity == Gravity.BOTTOM) {
                        if (rawY >= mMinRawY) {
                            mMinRawY = rawY;
                        } else {
                            mState = STATE_RETURNING;
                        }
                    } else if(mGravity == Gravity.TOP) {
                        if (rawY <= mMinRawY) {
                            mMinRawY = rawY;
                        } else {
                            mState = STATE_RETURNING;
                        }
                    }

                    translationY = rawY;
                    break;

                case STATE_ONSCREEN:
                    if(mGravity == Gravity.BOTTOM) {

                        if (rawY > mReturningViewHeight) {
                            mState = STATE_OFFSCREEN;
                            mMinRawY = rawY;
                        }
                    } else if(mGravity == Gravity.TOP) {

                        if (rawY < -mReturningViewHeight) {
                            mState = STATE_OFFSCREEN;
                            mMinRawY = rawY;
                        }
                    }
                    translationY = rawY;
                    break;

                case STATE_RETURNING:
                    if(mGravity == Gravity.BOTTOM) {
                        translationY = (rawY - mMinRawY) + mReturningViewHeight;

                        if (translationY < 0) {
                            translationY = 0;
                            mMinRawY = rawY + mReturningViewHeight;
                        }

                        if (rawY == 0) {
                            mState = STATE_ONSCREEN;
                            translationY = 0;
                        }

                        if (translationY > mReturningViewHeight) {
                            mState = STATE_OFFSCREEN;
                            mMinRawY = rawY;
                        }
                    } else if(mGravity == Gravity.TOP) {
                        translationY = (rawY + Math.abs(mMinRawY)) - mReturningViewHeight;

                        if (translationY > 0) {
                            translationY = 0;
                            mMinRawY = rawY - mReturningViewHeight;
                        }

                        if (rawY == 0) {
                            mState = STATE_ONSCREEN;
                            translationY = 0;
                        }

                        if (translationY < -mReturningViewHeight) {
                            mState = STATE_OFFSCREEN;
                            mMinRawY = rawY;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }

            /** this can be used if the build is below honeycomb **/
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, translationY, translationY);
                anim.setFillAfter(true);
                anim.setDuration(0);
                mReturningView.startAnimation(anim);
            } else {
                mReturningView.setTranslationY(translationY);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <yourpackagename.QuickReturnRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="15dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="New Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="New Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|top"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="New Button" />
    </LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

in `MainActivity.java` just add below lines

```
        mRecyclerView = (QuickReturnRecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
        // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
        // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // use a linear layout manager
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mRecyclerView.setReturningView(linear);
```